# col() in R gives warning message

Tags: r

on 6-month-old iMac with OSX v. 10.8.5 using R v 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) with either RStudio or Terminal this simple code:

`m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2)`

yields the expected 2x2 matrix and `row(m)` yields the expected 2x2 matrix with row 1s in the first row and 2s in the second.

But `col(m)` gave the following error:
`Warning message:  In seq. int(0, 1, length.out = n): first element used of 'length.out' argument.`

Curiously, the same code on a 5-year-old MacBook Air, OSX 10.6.8, but the same version of R gave the expected result for `col(m)` of 1's in the first col and 2s in the second.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried updating R to the last version (3.0.1)?

Comment: A warning message is not an error. It's coming up because `length.out` is being passed a vector of length > 1.

Comment: This is not reproducible. Also, that is a warning, not an error.

Comment: I would run `debug(seq.int)` and see what is getting passed.

Comment: Try typing in `col` to see if you accidentally overwrote the function.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by other posters, this works on a current version of R. Some suggestions to figure out why it produces a warning for you:

- Check that you do not have a custom function called "col" in your workspace. Try rm(col) to remove.
- Check if the following works

  ```
      .Internal(col(c(2L, 2L)))
  ```

  If this does not work, I would suspect that you have a strange R build and would suggest re-downloading from CRAN.
- If the internal command works, use debug() to find out what is happening.